# (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php44/usr/share/php') in /home/website/public_html/index.php on line 1 error

Tags: php

I have the following code on line 1 in my index.php file in the root directory of my server:

```
require_once ('../Connections/link.php');
```

and i have the Connections folder in the root directory as well which contains the connection file link.php.

When I try to open the website, the screen is blank and when i check the error log, i see the following error message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  main() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '../Connections/link.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php44/usr/share/php') in /home/website/public_html/index.php on line 1
```

I changed line 1 in index.php to:

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].('Connections/link.php');
```

And i get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  main() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '/home/website/public_htmlConnections/link.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php44/usr/share/php') in /home/nmecgov/public_html/index.php on line 1
```

If you notice their is no trailing forward slash in front of the Connections directory and so i added a / in front of it like below:

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].('/Connections/link.php');
```

And the webpage fails completely.

I don't know how to get this fixed

[Failed webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTpo1.png)

Comment: Have you tried `require_once ('Connections/link.php');` - since your script as the Connections folder are in root, this should work.

Comment: You need to look up the difference between `./` and `../` in the context of a path. Also, no parentheses are required around the path after `require` or `include`.

Comment: I tried require_once ('Connections/link.php');  and the webpage failed too

Comment: Isn't the problem obvious from the error message, Failed opening required '/home/website/public_htmlConnections/link.php?